# How to mount EFS with TLS (Encryption) inside a docker container on premises?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, amazon-efs

I am Trying to mount an EFS inside a docker container running on Premise.

I have tried it with no tls:

```
docker volume create \
        --driver local \
        --opt type=nfs \
        --opt o=addr=IP-12.29.29.29,rw,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,tls,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport \
    --opt device=:/ efs-test

docker run --rm -it -v /nfs:/nfs/test -v efs-test:/efs-test --name ubuntu -d ubuntu
```

it works fine. I can access EFS and write data.

If I use the encryption option while creating the volume, i create a en error:

```
docker volume create \
        --driver local \
        --opt type=nfs \
        --opt o=addr=IP-12.29.29.29,rw,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,tls,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport \
        --opt device=:/ efs-test

docker run --rm -it -v /nfs/efs/:/nas/test -v efs-test:/efs-test --name sync -d sync


docker: Error response from daemon: error while mounting volume 
'/global/docker/volumes/efs-test/_data': failed to mount local volume: mount :/:/global/docker/volumes/efs-test/_data, 
    data: addr=10.3.77.107,nfsvers=4.1,rsize=1048576,tls,wsize=1048576,hard,timeo=600,retrans=2,noresvport: invalid argument.
```

How do I mount an EFS with TLS from on premises using Docker?